# windows 7 firewall blocks edge traversal(port forward from router)

Tags: windows-7, port-forwarding, windows-firewall

I am trying to set up a website on my windows 7 machine. I opened a 'inbound rule' in firewall to open port 8000. When I try to visit the port from another computer in my home network, it works fine.

However, I also want people outside my home network to visit my website. So I set up a port forwarding on my home router, to forward port 8000 to 8000. When I try to visit the port from outside, it does not work. I have a linux server in my home and set up the port forward, and it works fine.

So I am sure that the router is set correctly, and the real problem is in windows firewall. The fact is that local computer in my home network can visit the port while outside computer cannot. And in the inbound rule, which is set in windows firewall, I select 'Allow edge traversal' explicitly, but it still does not work.

Anyone can help me?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score -1):

If a user can access the website from inside the network, but an outside user cannot, it's almost always a NAT problem on the router.

But just in case, lets say it's not a router problem.

You would want to check to make sure that the scope of the Windows Firewall rule allows all IP addresses, and not just those that are within your local subnet.

Comment: Yes. I checked Any remote IP address is allowed.

Comment: Then it's almost certainly a NAT problem.  I'd re-check the rule you put in your router to be sure that you didn't accidentally fat-finger an IP address or something along those lines.

Comment: That is so strange. I re-check the rule, and it's good. The strange thing is I have other Linux machines having NAT rules, they are working fine. Only this windows machine has problem.

Comment: @Sector95 You write "If a user can access the website from inside the network, but an outside user cannot, it's almost always a NAT problem on the router." <-- how on earth are you determining that it's a NAT issue and not a firewall issue.

Comment: @barlop wow this is 8 years old, talk about a necro-comment... But a quick reread of the question and my answer leads me to believe that I don't care anymore.